# Earliest recorded instance and geographical spread of the idea that banging your head on your pillow N times can ensure that you wake up at N o'clock?

Tags: folklore

Some people believe and report the effectiveness of a method of ensuring they wake at a certain time that consists of banging their head against their pillow the required number of times before they go to sleep. For instance, if they wish to wake up at 8 o'clock, they bang eight times.

What is the earliest recorded instance of this belief and practice? And how far has it spread geographically? (I encountered it in England.)

Answer (score 3):

The earliest published reference I have found to this belief is by **E C Nesbit's character Caroline in *The Wonderful Garden or The Three Cs*, 1911**:

> "No, we must hide him, and wake him before they call us. I can always
>   wake up if  I bang my head the right number of times on the pillow
>   before I go to sleep."